# How to convert the index of a flatten multidimensional array (any depth) to the original index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

For example, suppose I have a multidimensional array:

```
const a1=[["a",["a","b"]],"b",[["b"],"c"]];
```

which the flatten from is

```
const a2=["a","a","b","b","c","c"];
```

and accessing a2[2] is equivalent to a1[0][1][1], also access a2[3] is equivalent to a1[1].

However I'm not interested in what the element is in such index, instead I want a function that can convert the index of a2 equivalent to in a1, eg:

```
magicFunction(2,[["a",["a","b"]],"b",[["b"],"c"]])
```

returns [0,1,1],

also

```
magicFunction(3,[["a",["a","b"]],"b",[["b"],"c"]])
```

returns [1]. And the input multidimensional array can be any depth (more than 3 layers). How do I write such magic function?

Note: I know that may be easy to do if I know the array is 2d and the sub-array have same number of elements:

```js
const a1=[["a","a"],["b","b"],["c","c"]];
const magicFunction=function(target,a){
  let count=0;
  for(let i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    for(let j=0;j<a[i].length;j++){
        if(count==target){
            return [i,j];
        }
        count++;
    }
  }
  return [];
};
alert(magicFunction(3,a1));
```

However now I need the function to accept a with n-dimensional array which d is unknown before testing, which I don't know how many layers of for-loop should I write to handle it, also the length of each sub-array may not be the same.

Comment: "_accessing a2[2] is equivalent to a1[0][1][1], also access a2[3] is equivalent to a1[1]_":  They both reference the string `"b"`, and JavaScript makes no discrimination between identical strings. Flattening an array is a lossy operation: you can't recover the hierarchy of index relationships. At best, you can do a traversal to find the nth occurrence of a target value using a value comparison algorithm (e.g. `Object.is` or your own implementation).

Comment: The alternative is to flatten into an array of tuples like `Array<[value, array of property accessors]>`, then you can easily select the second tuple member to get your desired result.

Comment: Flattening together with arrays of indexes is a way to go. Shouldn't be difficult, assuming this is a school assignment we could let the OP work on this on their own.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive function that generates the path by traversing the array and counting values until it reaches the n'th value. The function returns either an array of the path (if we reach the n'th value) or the current count (if we don't).

```js
const magicFunction = (index, array, count=0) => {
  for (let idx = 0; idx < array.length; idx++) {
    if (Array.isArray(array[idx])) {
      let res = magicFunction(index, array[idx], count)
      if (Array.isArray(res)) return [idx].concat(res)
      else count = res
    }
    else {
      if (count == index) return [idx]
      count++
    }
  }
  return count
}

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  res = magicFunction(i, [["a",["b","c"]],"d",[["e"],"f"]])
  console.log(`${i} : [${res}]`)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten an array into a list of `[element path]` pairs and fetch paths from that list:

```js
function* flatWithPaths(a, parent=[]) {
    for (let [i, e] of a.entries()) {
        if (Array.isArray(e))
            yield* flatWithPaths(e, parent.concat(i))
        else
            yield [e, parent.concat(i)]
    }
}

//

const a = [["a",["b","c"]],"d",[["e","f"],[[["g","h"]]]]]

let n = 0

for (let [elem, path] of flatWithPaths(a)) {
    console.log(n++, elem, path.join())

}
```